# Cyclical observable with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a view which presents as seen in the following screen grab:

[image]

On clicking an item from the *Views* column, the *Available Columns* list is populated. When the user then clicks a different item from the *Views* list, the *Available Columns* list needs to be reset and populated with columns relevant to the newly selected *View*

In my knockout view model I have the following subscriptions and computed:

```
self.columnsToAdd.subscribe(function (items) {
    var viewIndex = findViewIndex(self.selectedView().ViewId);
    //delete columns from the selected view then add in those that are in the 
    //columnsToAdd list
    data.Users[0].Views[viewIndex].VisibleColumns.length = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        data.Users[0].Views[viewIndex].VisibleColumns.push(view = {ColumnId:items[i].ColumnId, Heading:items[i].Heading});
    }
});

self.selectedView.subscribe(function (item) {
    //clear columnsToAdd then re-populate
    //this line is causing data.Users[0].Views[0].VisibleColumns to be reset
    //because it triggers the columnsToAdd.Subscribe
    self.columnsToAdd([]); 
    var view = getById(self.views, item.ViewId);
    for (i = 0; i < view.VisibleColumns.length; i++) {
        self.columnsToAdd.push(view.VisibleColumns[i]);
    }
});

self.allColumns = ko.computed(function () {
    var view = getById(self.views, self.selectedView().ViewId);
    return view ? ko.utils.arrayMap(view.AllColumns, function (item) {
        return {
            ColumnId: item.Id,
            Heading: item.Heading
        };
    }) : [];
}, this);
```

As can be seen in my code comments, the problem is with the subscription of the *selectedView* observable. This is bound to the selected item of the *Views*
 list. When this changes I need to clear down the *Available Columns* list but this then causes the subscription of the bound observable array to fire which then clears out the *VisibleColumns* observable array, needed by the selectedView subscription.

Is there a standard pattern to use to solve such problems with knockoutjs?

Comment: I'd have two collections on each views view model--AvailableColumns and ToDisplay. Then I'd have SelectedAvailableColumn and SelectedToDisplay observables.  I'd bind each list to each collection, and the selection to each observable.  Now, when you click the button, you take SelectedAvailableColumn, remove it from AvailableColumns, then add it to SelectedToDisplay.  That's all you need to do, as long as the instances are the same, everything should wire up easily.

Comment: Thanks will, you made me realise that I had over complicated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove the subscription on *columnsToAdd* observable array. Instead, I update the backing view model's *VisibleColumns* collections of the *Views* collections within the events for the *Add* and *Remove* buttons:

```
self.addColumn = function () {
        if (self.columnsToAdd().indexOf(self.selectedAvailableColumn()) < 0) {
            self.columnsToAdd.push(self.selectedAvailableColumn());
            data.Users[0].Views[self.viewIndex].VisibleColumns.push(self.selectedAvailableColumn())
        }
    };

    self.removeColumn = function () {
        self.columnsToAdd.remove(self.selectedColumnToRemove());
        data.Users[0].Views[self.viewIndex].VisibleColumns.pop(self.selectedAvailableColumn())
    };
```