# Uncaught TypeError: grid.sortedData.peek(...).filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

I'm trying to make paging work with the KnockoutJs KOGrid. I've been following this: http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#paging

The data that I'm passing into my view model (the vm param) contains the following:

[image]

My knockout view model is as follows:

```
function ViewModel(vm) {
    var self = this;
    this.myData = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.rows = ko.observableArray(vm.Rows);

    this.deleteInvisibleColumns = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.Rows.length; i++) {
            var row = vm.Rows[i];

            var keys = Object.keys(row);
            for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                if (vm.VisibleColumns.indexOf(keys[k]) === (-1)) {
                    delete row[keys[k]];
                };
            };
        };
    };  

    self.deleteInvisibleColumns();

    this.filterOptions = {
        filterText: ko.observable(""),
        useExternalFilter: true
    };

    this.pagingOptions = {
        pageSizes: ko.observableArray([2, 500, 1000]),
        pageSize: ko.observable(2),
        totalServerItems: ko.observable(0),
        currentPage: ko.observable(1)     
    };

    this.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){    
        var pagedRows = data.Rows.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        var pagedData = { Rows: pagedRows, VisibleColumns: data.VisibleColumns };

        self.myData(pagedData);
        self.pagingOptions.totalServerItems(data.Rows.length);
    };

    this.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var data;
            if (searchText) {
                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                $.getJSON('/SampleData/GetDataPage', function (returnedPayload) {
                    data = returnedPayload.filter(function (item) {
                        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    });
                    self.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
                });          
            } else {
                $.getJSON('/SampleData/GetDataPage', function (returnedPayload) {
                    self.setPagingData(returnedPayload, page, pageSize);
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    };

    self.filterOptions.filterText.subscribe(function (data) {
        self.getPagedDataAsync(self.pagingOptions.pageSize(), self.pagingOptions.currentPage(), self.filterOptions.filterText());
    });   

    self.pagingOptions.pageSizes.subscribe(function (data) {
        self.getPagedDataAsync(self.pagingOptions.pageSize(), self.pagingOptions.currentPage(), self.filterOptions.filterText());
    });
    self.pagingOptions.pageSize.subscribe(function (data) {
        self.getPagedDataAsync(self.pagingOptions.pageSize(), self.pagingOptions.currentPage(), self.filterOptions.filterText());
    });
    self.pagingOptions.totalServerItems.subscribe(function (data) {
        self.getPagedDataAsync(self.pagingOptions.pageSize(), self.pagingOptions.currentPage(), self.filterOptions.filterText());
    });
    self.pagingOptions.currentPage.subscribe(function (data) {
        self.getPagedDataAsync(self.pagingOptions.pageSize(), self.pagingOptions.currentPage(), self.filterOptions.filterText());
    });

    self.getPagedDataAsync(self.pagingOptions.pageSize(), self.pagingOptions.currentPage());

    this.gridOptions = {
        data: self.myData,
        enablePaging: true,
        pagingOptions: self.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: self.filterOptions
    };  
};
```

Andy my html (Asp.Net MVC Razor view) is:

```
@model ESB.BamPortal.Website.Models.SampleDataViewModel
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sample Data";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@{  string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model); }

<div id="Knockout" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions">
</div>



@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/KnockoutVM/SampleData.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/KoGrid.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vm = new ViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("Knockout"));
    </script>
}
```

When the page loads, the following error is being thrown from within kogrid.js *Uncaught TypeError: grid.sortedData.peek(...).filter is not a function*

```
self.evalFilter = function () {
        if (searchConditions.length === 0) {
            grid.filteredData(grid.sortedData.peek().filter(function(item) {
```

If I inspect the *sortedData* property of the *grid* object it looks ok:

[image]

The last line of my knockout viewmodel js to execute is *self.myData(pagedData);* within the *this.SetPagingData* function.

Using Fiddler I pulled the following out of the response from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var vm = new ViewModel({"Rows":[{"SampleDataId":1,"Manufacturer":"Ford","Model":"Escort","Style":"Hatch"},{"SampleDataId":2,"Manufacturer":"Vauxhall","Model":"Cavalier","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":3,"Manufacturer":"Rover","Model":"Montego","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":4,"Manufacturer":"Ford","Model":"Escort","Style":"Hatch"},{"SampleDataId":5,"Manufacturer":"Vauxhall","Model":"Cavalier","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":6,"Manufacturer":"Rover","Model":"Montego","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":7,"Manufacturer":"Opel","Model":"Monza","Style":"Coupe"},{"SampleDataId":8,"Manufacturer":"BMW","Model":"325i","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":9,"Manufacturer":"Ford","Model":"Escort","Style":"Hatch"},{"SampleDataId":10,"Manufacturer":"Vauxhall","Model":"Cavalier","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":11,"Manufacturer":"Rover","Model":"Montego","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":12,"Manufacturer":"Opel","Model":"Monza","Style":"Coupe"},{"SampleDataId":13,"Manufacturer":"BMW","Model":"325i","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":14,"Manufacturer":"Ford","Model":"Escort","Style":"Hatch"},{"SampleDataId":15,"Manufacturer":"Vauxhall","Model":"Cavalier","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":16,"Manufacturer":"Rover","Model":"Montego","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":17,"Manufacturer":"Opel","Model":"Monza","Style":"Coupe"},{"SampleDataId":18,"Manufacturer":"BMW","Model":"325i","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":19,"Manufacturer":"Ford","Model":"Escort","Style":"Hatch"},{"SampleDataId":20,"Manufacturer":"Vauxhall","Model":"Cavalier","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":21,"Manufacturer":"Rover","Model":"Montego","Style":"Saloon"},{"SampleDataId":22,"Manufacturer":"Opel","Model":"Monza","Style":"Coupe"},{"SampleDataId":23,"Manufacturer":"BMW","Model":"325i","Style":"Saloon"}],"VisibleColumns":[]});
        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("Knockout"));
    </script>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi, you can give a try for this [project](https://github.com/jmvtrinidad/knockout-datagrid). It is more easy to use for `server-side processing` or `JavaScript source`.

Comment: Thanks but I really would like to make kogrid work, it has lots of features that would be useful

Comment: Its ok, the value that retrieve from your source is not an array, that's why the filter from array prototype is not working.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that. I notice that the 'Demo' link from your github page returns a 404?

Comment: Thanks for informing, I already updated the [project](https://github.com/jmvtrinidad/knockout-datagrid).

Comment: Hi, In line 1677 can you execute in console this line `grid.sortedData.peek()`. update me for the result. Thanks.

Comment: Rob, can you provide full json with your table data?

Comment: I have now added the json response from the server

Comment: You have to put an **array** and not a complex object to `myData` if it is used in as the grid's data. So in `SetPagingData` you need to write `self.myData(pagedData.Rows);`. It is also not clear what is your goal with the additional VisibleColumns property? As a sidenote: You are currently don't do proper server side paging. Because you don't pass any paramters to the server and you process your returned data on the client side.

Comment: Sorry for the delay nemesv, I was forced to work-around the problem due to time constraints but I would like to make the knockout grid work if possible. I will try your suggestion tonight. Re the purpose of the VisibleColumns property, perhaps my previous post will clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731384/cyclical-observable-with-knockoutjs

Comment: nemesv you got it! Many thanks, please add as answer and I will mark as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correctly specifying a `ko.observableArray` property (`myData`) as `data` parameter of the `gridOptions` object, however **you have to make sure that it always contains an JavaScript array.**

Knockout does not "type-check" what you put into an `ko.observableArray` so you need to make sure that you always use arrays.

However in your `setPagingData` you try to assign an object to your `myData` instead of an **array**, and this throws this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: grid.sortedData.peek(...).filter is not a function

because a plain JavaScript object litaral does not have a `filter` function.

The fix is quite easy, you just need to pass `pagedData.Rows` as the value of `myData`:

```
this.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){    
        var pagedRows = data.Rows.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        var pagedData = { Rows: pagedRows, VisibleColumns: data.VisibleColumns };

        self.myData(pagedData.Rows);
        self.pagingOptions.totalServerItems(data.Rows.length);
    };
```

Sidenote: Your current implementation does not do a proper server side paging. Because you don't pass any parameters to the server and you process the returned data on the client side.